# Rails DNS Caching Issue on Mac

Tags: macos, caching, dns

I'm attempting to reach my rails app located at `https://theoremreach.com` on my mac but it seems to refuse all connections from my mac OSX Yosemite (tried curl, firefox, chrome, even a webview in an iOS app). If I go to it form any other computer/android/iPhone, it works just fine. So I know the site is up but I cannot get it to load on my mac.

So it seems like a DNS caching error. However, I've tried `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` and `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and neither did the trick. Any ideas what I should do to clear the cache so I can get to the website?

Comment: This may seem silly but do you have your etc/hosts file pointed locally?

Comment: OH MY GOSH YOU ARE AMAZING. I think I stupidly edited that a while ago following something.... sheesh. Wow thank you! Want to toss that in as an answer?

Comment: hehe oversight happens to the best of us. :) Added it as a answer. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your hosts /etc/hosts file so it's not pointed locally.